# Show All Tasks Assigned to Me (including those assigned to Me and Multiple Users)

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, task-list

I have a Task List WP on my Site Page and I want it to show all Tasks Assigned to Me (my name is Jay Scott). This includes both of the following Tasks:

- TASK 1: Assigned to Me only, *ex. 'Assigned to: Jay Scott*
- TASK 2: Assigned to ME **and** my coworker Joey Cape, *ex. Assigned to Jay Scott; Joey Cape*

The issue I face is that 'Assigned To' is not able to be filtered by 'Contains [Me]', so I am forced to filter by 'Assigned To Equals [Me]', where everything must be an exact match. As a result, Task 2 does not show up on my filtered Task List. I would prefer to not create groups, as there's an infinite amount of possible combinations of users and groups. How can I solve for this?

*Prior to posting, I searched and found similar questions, but those involved either changing a setting in the 'Assigned to' column (forcing an SP prompt saying I might lose data) or Group.*

Comment: The way you are doing it should filter you in if multiple people are in the same column--if you are using the People/Group data column type. May be a bug in SharePoint Online. I have it working correctly in SP2010

Comment: Currently, the 'Assigned To' column is allowing multiple selections, and allowing people an groups. When I attempt to alter that, I get a notification from SharePoint that I may lose data, including ALL names but the first name in every Assigned To column -- which, clearly would be problematic

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If you are included in a list of users in the same column. The filter <People/Group Column> eq [Me] should work in the manner you provided. You shouldn't have to be the only one listed for it to work.

Comment: No dice. Not working.

Comment: Can you try a new page, or another list? Maybe the view was modified beyond just that filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the view ...

"By My Groups" 
[image]

Comment: I don't have this list view option OOTB. Is this a custom view you've made?

Comment: No, it is a standard view for "task list"

Answer (score 1):

I am on the SharePoint online site and I can see my tasks even it is assigned to multiple users.

[image]

Here is a filter in My Tasks.

[image]

The only case I don`t see the is if the task is assigned to an AD group versus an individual user.